How do i check if two stream of data is same Databricks vs sql server ( native)
We are migrating our legacy data stored in multiple tables to new Azure Databricks environment
context :  earlier a lot of .net application were streaming data into sql server( in multiple tables) ,now we have azure event hub that will store data in azure data lake and then using spark structured streaming will flow into databricks delta tables.
issue : How do i check the data in old SQL server tables vs new data bricks tables, because there will be lag between the two systems and multiple events upsert data into multiple tables (many to many).
any guidance will be helpful
comparing two tables
